# How to autocomplete mobile number using Jquery-ui?

Tags: jquery

Can someone show me jquery autocomplete for mobile number,if the user put a cell number previously 
and come back again to put the same number it must autocomplete the previous one.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Allow your browser to store your inputs.

There is no exact method that can catch previous entered inputs but if you anyway store your inputs in local browser storage, on window load you can use this method to autofill input box,

```
$(function() {
var availableOptions = getArrayOfPrevoiusInputsFromLocalStorage;
$( "#phone" ).autocomplete({
   source: availableOptions 
 });
});
```

To use this method you have to do the following things,
1) On Submitt Save all of your desired input in your local browser storage with a specified name,
2) On Window Load Apply above mention method, and Don't forget to get array of previous inputs by you method in my case I'm using **getArrayOfPrevoiusInputsFromLocalStorage** method to get this array, then apply to your input.